Keep only entries in a data frame with the largest group of elements
I have this exact data frame, only a bit longer:
mydf <- data.frame(ids=c('D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7','D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1','D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8','D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7','D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8//D3026TexC2','D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7','D3019TexA5//D3022TexB4//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3','D3021TexA7//D3021TexA10','D3022TexB8//D3026TexC4','D3022TexB6//D3022TexB9','D3022TexA2//D3026TexC5','D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7','D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3'),
                   rank=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4),
                   group=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))

It looks like the following, with groups of ids separated by //, and their ranking:
> mydf
                                              ids rank group
1                          D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    1     1
2                         D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1    1     2
3                          D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8    2     1
4                          D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    2     2
5              D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8//D3026TexC2    3     1
6                          D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    3     2
7  D3019TexA5//D3022TexB4//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     1
8                         D3021TexA7//D3021TexA10    4     2
9                          D3022TexB8//D3026TexC4    4     3
10                         D3022TexB6//D3022TexB9    4     4
11                         D3022TexA2//D3026TexC5    4     5
12                         D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    4     6
13            D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     7

First thing I want to accomplish, is to remove duplicated ids entries, keeping the entry with the lowest rank number (as in keep 1 over 3, for example).
I could do this like this:
mydf <- mydf[!duplicated(mydf$ids),]

However, some smaller id groups are contained inside larger groups (and they might not be in the same order), and in that case, I want to keep the larger groups.
All in all, my expected output would be the following, but I don´t know how to obtain it... any clues? Thanks!
> mydf_final
                                              ids rank group
1                          D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    1     1
5              D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8//D3026TexC2    3     1
7  D3019TexA5//D3022TexB4//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     1
8                         D3021TexA7//D3021TexA10    4     2
9                          D3022TexB8//D3026TexC4    4     3
10                         D3022TexB6//D3022TexB9    4     4
11                         D3022TexA2//D3026TexC5    4     5
13            D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     7

EDIT:
Let's try with a simpler example... I want to remove shorter groups whose all elements are contained in larger groups.
If I have groups A/B/C/D,  A/B, A/E, A/Z, A/B/C, A/B/E, A/B/C/F...
I want to keep A/B/C/D, A/Z, A/B/E, A/B/C/F
Groups A/B, A/E, A/B/C have all their elements contained in larger groups.

It is hard to grasp the structure. I would split each ids on "//", append to my_df, and then develope a technique which checks for any duplicate in up to four cols between all (this is the hard part I suspect) rows. After having created a unique group identifier group2, I would select the maximum group for each group2. It is worth knowing if this is what you want before writing some code to accomplish. Otherwise please explain the logic on detail (with at least one example).

Shouldn't the last line D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3 also be filtered out, since D3026TexC1 and D3026TexC3 are duplicates and in the shorter group?

Sorry for the late response; the last line shouldn't be filtered out, cause not all its elements are included in a longer group... group A/B/C should be excluded if A/B/C/D is present (cause it includes all elements of A/B/C), but group A/B/F is already a different group and should not be excluded

See my edit with explaining the logic with a simpler example

You can use aggregate and min functions from Base R as follow:
mydf_final <- aggregate(cbind(rank, group) ~ ids, min, data = mydf)
o <- order(mydf_final$rank) # to order it
mydf_final[o,]

OUTPUT
                                              ids rank group
6                          D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    1     1
9                         D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1    1     2
2                          D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8    2     1
3              D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8//D3026TexC2    3     1
1  D3019TexA5//D3022TexB4//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     1
4                         D3021TexA7//D3021TexA10    4     2
5                          D3022TexA2//D3026TexC5    4     5
7                          D3022TexB6//D3022TexB9    4     4
8                          D3022TexB8//D3026TexC4    4     3
10            D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     7


its different to op's  mydf_final?

yeah, this is quite different... please see my edit for a simple example explaining the logic of what I want to do. Thanks!

Attending the latest edition made of first post, we could provide de following code:
# Convertion of ids to list of vector
list <- lapply(paste0("c('", gsub("//", "','", mydf$ids), "')"), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))

# Comparison of each id group
res <- NULL
for (i in seq_along(list)) {
    res <- c(res, sum(unlist(lapply(list, function(x) prod(list[[i]] %in% x) == 1 & length(x) > length(list[[i]])))))
}
mydf2 <- mydf[ifelse(res == 1, F, T),]

# Final Step, grouping
mydf3 <- aggregate(cbind(rank, group) ~ ids, min, data = mydf2)
o <- order(mydf3$rank, mydf3$group) # to order it
mydf_final <- mydf3[o,]

OUTPUT
                                             ids rank group
5                         D3022TexB4//D3022TexB7    1     1
2             D3021TexA6//D3022TexC8//D3026TexC2    3     1
1 D3019TexA5//D3022TexB4//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     1
3                        D3021TexA7//D3021TexA10    4     2
7                         D3022TexB8//D3026TexC4    4     3
6                         D3022TexB6//D3022TexB9    4     4
4                         D3022TexA2//D3026TexC5    4     5
8            D3022TexC10//D3026TexC1//D3026TexC3    4     7

